Using blender alpha hashed the model becomes transparent. I don't want the model to look transparent
Using blender alpha hashed the model becomes transparent. I don't want the model to look transparent
like this

origin is

enter image description here



What do you mean you “used” the blend and shadow method settings? They are ALWAYS used.

I tried opaque change to alpha hashed, but like an under the photo, they are changed transparent，my English is not good， I'm so sorry

another option is not transparent， just alpha hashed will be transparent

Oh, I see. Alpha Blend is notorious for bad Z sorting, making things appear in front of other things when they are not. Alpha Hashed is more reliable but not as pretty.

should i continue to use the alpha hashed？ even they look transparent？or any other solution？

That sounds like somewhere in the material it is set to be transparent, but while the blend method was set to opaque the setting was ignored. Add a screenshot of your node setup, please.

I cannot tell as easily what inputs are what in Chinese, but try disconnecting the image's alpha channel from the Principled BSDF's alpha input. That channel is clearly used in the game for something besides transparency (such as roughness).

sounds great thank you lab cat
